# Baire property for finite discrete spaces

Tags: general-topology

Does it makes sense to assume that a nonempty open set of a finite discrete topological space has the Baire property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: every set is open, hence any set differs from an open set by the most meagre of all sets: $\varnothing$.